# Ajax not passing by post method to php

Tags: php, ajax

Im using google chrome 65.0.3325.181 on windows 10, xampp is on to run the php. title explains the rest.

html/php:

```
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $('#sel_edificio').load('data.php');

        $( ".form-control" ).change(function() {

            var dato = 50;//document.getElementById("sel_edificio").value;

            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                data: {'key': dato},
                url: "uno.php",
                success: function(status){
                    var asd = $('#test').load('uno.php');
                    //document.getElementById("NumEstudiantes").value(key);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

uno.php:

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['key'];
?>
```

error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: key in C:\xampp\htdocs\jqbd\uno.php on line 2
```

Comment: Try comment out that `.load()`, replace it with `console.log(status)`. You will know what happened.

Comment: @VinhVO it is showing me a lot of information but none about the error, had to put the error() function to see it.

Comment: I meant you `load` the `uno.php` file to the `#test` element, this file does not have any POST param at all, that why it throws you the error. The ajax looks fine.

Comment: why do you use this part `var asd = $('#test').load('uno.php');` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending request two time, try this:

**html/php**

```
 $(document).ready(function (){

    $('#sel_edificio').load('data.php');

    $( ".form-control" ).change(function() {

        var dato = 50;//document.getElementById("sel_edificio").value;

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            data: {'key': dato},
            url: "uno.php",
            success: function(data){
                $('#test').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This fixed the issue. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

change ajax method to type, try this

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: {'key': dato},
                dataType: "json",
                url: "uno.php",
                success: function(status){
                    //var asd = $('#test').load('uno.php');
                    $('#test').load('uno.php', { key: dato });//document.getElementById("NumEstudiantes").value(key);
                }
            });
```

Comment: im having the same error but i had to do this to see it: error(status) { $('#test').load('uno.php'); }

Comment: It is not fixed yet